# Secure OS for Website managing

Tags: password-management

I'm starting a new website project where I have many passwords (root,sql,wordpress, etc).
I have a USB stick encrypted with TrueCrypt with a file of all my passwords. But I also want to be safe if i open the file and type it into the Internet. Of course it would be possible to store them on some paper but some kind of keylogger or whatever would not keep my passwords secure. That's why I've been thinking of some secure Virtual Machine. Windows 8 with AntiVir software and firewall but else *usual use*. In the OS a secure VM.
Would that be a safe setup or as safe as without VM?

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about the passwords for managing your website or business here's the approach I'd recommend.

- Have an entirely separate physical machine for management work.  Do not use it for any other tasks (e-mail, website browsing etc etc).
- Don't install any other software onto the device (e.g. Java, adobe acrobat, flash) unless needed.
- Ensure that it's got up-to-date firewall and anti-malware protection.
- Use an encrypted container for your passwords.
- Keep the devices in a locked drawer or cabinet when not in use.

the problem with using a Virtual Machine instead of a physical machine is that a keylogger on the host Operating system may well still get your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here, even if you set up a "secure" VM you will still need to type the password into your applications, regardless if you store it in an encrypted file, password manager or a virtual machine.

If you say you don't trust all machines where you need to input or save your passwords then I suggest not using the machine at all.